# ASP.NET page in subdirectory: $(document).ready() only works if I'm using CDN-hosted version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm a little stumped by this. I have an ASP.NET web application, and I'm using the stock version of jQuery that ships with VS2010, 1.4.1 (though I can reproduce this issue in later versions of jQuery).

I have a **Default.aspx** page in the root folder of my web application, and in it, is this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Some content here...
    </h2>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          alert("Page loaded, awesome!")
      });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

That works great. Now, I also have a **Login.aspx** page sitting in the stock **Account** subfolder of a new ASP.NET web application. On this page, this **does not work**:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Imagine there are some Log In controls in here...
    </h2>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           alert("Page loaded, awesome!")
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

However, as soon as I change to something like this (using the CDN hosted version of jQuery)...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       alert("Page loaded, awesome!")
    });
</script>
```

...then things work great. I'm assuming there is something that I'm doing something wrong regarding the path I'm using to my local copy of jQuery, but I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. I shouldn't need to use a CDN hosted copy of jQuery, especially when a local copy works on pages in the root folder of my web application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging, it turned out to be a security issue. Adding this into my `web.config` resolved it:

```
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the path correct ?

Try this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Imagine there are some Log In controls in here...
    </h2>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           alert("Page loaded, awesome!")
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

or change it to:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I think it is more not seeing your jquery then anything.  Can you use firebug to debug the issue?

**You should also put a semi colon after the alert.**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Imagine there are some Log In controls in here...
    </h2>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           alert("Page loaded, awesome!");
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: That was my first thought. It doesn't seem to matter whether or not I use `../Scripts` or '~/Scripts', I get the same issue - ready() is never invoked.

Comment: At design time does visual studio see this file ?  Drag and drop this jquery file into your aspx markup and post what it's path is.

Comment: The path I get when I drag & drop it is this: <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ... however, using that does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @unforgiven3 - and so it does see this file, can you place a semi colon after the alert and run the web page with the debugger on.  Use f12 for IE or firebug or chromes analyzer to see if you get any js errors.

Comment: Just to test place the same jquery file in the accounts folder and reference that file with just script `src = jquery-1.4.1.js` so it would be at the same level as your .aspx page, then run your web project, does the alert then come up ?

Comment: Hmm, no, even copying it to the accounts folder - still does not work.

Comment: Yes - clearing cache doesn't seem to help either. Really weird.

Comment: last test and then Im done, create a new page in that same folder, reference the jquery directly on that page with a copy of the jquery file.  See if the issue goes away...its almost like you are having some sort of security issue.  Like I said copy the jquery file and place it in the same directory with a new .aspx page.  Make it simple with one alert and valid syntax (dont forget the ;).

Comment: I'll give that a try. Security seems like the most likely issue here. Really, really bizarre.

Comment: Just an fyi I just tried this out and ended up using `<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and it worked perfectly fine for me.  I even placed the .aspx page in a sub directory.

Comment: I get the same problem, even with a new page. I see a JS issue: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"... looks to be because the JS isn't getting loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the tilde (~) to make the path correct.

Also, for efficiency purposes, you will do better to place your entire script at the end of the page and just get rid of the surrounding $(document).ready() construct.  This will process in the same way but, because it isn't loaded until the HTML has been parsed, it will run faster (per Nicholas Zakas' ["High Performance Javascript"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X)).

UPDATE: I have to apologize to jrummel - I downvoted his post about using runat server.  Looking further, I found this post: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/453237-specifying-javascript-file-path-master-pages discussing the use of javascript files in master pages.  It turns out that the tilde is Ok **but** you have to include runat="server" to make it substitute out correctly.  So, *if* you use a tilde then you must also use the runat='server':

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" runat="server"></script>
```

in order to tell the parser to interpret the tilde.

If you don't include one, then don't include the other.  I would still recommend a simple, root-based path:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

ANOTHER EFFICIENCY UPDATE:

Just to take Zakas' "High Performance" thinking one step further, I'll note that he recommends just including the javascript files right in the body of your page so that the browser isn't required to make a separate trip to the server to pull the file.  The way to do this in ASP.NET is to include the following (again, at the end of the file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--#include file="/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" -->
...other javascript files...

Your javascript functions and commands here.  Again, no "ready" function is needed...

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use '~/' or '../', it does not work. I'm more concerned with understanding why ready() works fine on my Default.aspx page, but not on my Login page, than I am with efficiency.

Comment: @unforgiven3 - to see why it doesnt work see my last comment on my post.  Place the jquery file in the same path as the .aspx file so that you state `src=jquery...` and then run your app.

Comment: Unless I'm completely misunderstanding, I tried just adding the JS for jQuery at the end of my master page; ready() did not appear to work. Beyond that, I don't understand what you mean by "again, no ready function is needed" - can you elaborate on that?

Comment: And `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" runat="server"></script>` does not appear to work either; I still get JS errors that appear to indicate the JS file was not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Page.ResolveClientUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx).

```
<script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Update:

The problem is that based on the relative path of your page, the script path will change. `ResolveClientUrl()` will take into account the page path and figure out the relative script path.

Comment: "Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs."

Comment: Forgot to remove `runat="server"`. Try it now.

Comment: Still no luck, even with `runat="server"` removed.

Comment: Yes, JS errors: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"` and `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`... looks to be because jQuery isn't getting loaded.

Comment: If you view source in Chrome and then click on the jquery script src, does it load the js file? If so, you've got another problem on your page.

Comment: No, it does not load the JS file from View Source :-(